# Creating array of integer for every proccess in python

Tags: python, arrays

So I'm doing some research, and everytime I get data from arduino serial, I exported it to a text file. What I need do is to make an array of integer so that it is easy to process. In my code below, where should I put the array so that every process is count

```
import time
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM3',9600)
fileteks = open("newfile.txt","w")
while 1:
    if ser.inWaiting():  
         x=ser.readline()
         print (x[:-2],time.ctime())
         fileteks.write(str(x[:-2]))
         fileteks.write(str(time.ctime()))
         fileteks.write('\n')
    if x=="\n\r":
        fileteks.truncate()
        fileteks.flush()
fileteks.close()
ser.close()
```

This is my code... where do I put the array so every process is count
sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Can you fix the identation because it is wrong?

Comment: I made an effort to edit the indentation but might have gotten it wrong. Waiting for someone else to check it.

Comment: Someone else can't read the OP's mind...they can only guess at the indentation of your code. In Python, indentation is extremely important.

Comment: idnawsi: After your edit, the indentation is still wrong.